# Strip URL only display domain

Tags: php, url

I have a url, http://members.exampledomain.com, and I would like to display only exampledomain onto my page. strip out 'http://members' and '.com'

For example http://members.exampledomain.com's index page has something like

```
<img src="members/images/logo<?=$exampledomain; ?>.png" />
```

ok this worked:

```
<?php
 $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

 $ArrayOfStrings = explode(".", $url);

 echo $ArrayOfStrings[1];
 include("variables/" . $ArrayOfStrings[1] . "/config.inc");
 ?>
```

Comment: You already have the correct function as a tag, what's the difficulty?

Comment: Im using this script but its printing members instead of exampledomain

Comment: `code`<?php
function URLVariable() {
 $url = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$url .= "s";}
 $url .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }

$urlarray=explode("//",$url);
$subdomain = $urlarray[1];
$returnvalue=explode(".",$subdomain);
return $returnvalue[0];
}
?>
<? $urlvar = URLVariable(); ?>
<?=$urlvar; ?>`code`

Comment: what will happen when **exampledomain.com** and **exampledomain.net** wanted to use

Comment: @Hector, don't use `[code]` tags. Wrap your code in ticks (the key to the left of `1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included an explode tag. I'm assuming you are looking for help using the explode function?

```
 <?php
 $url = "http://memebers.exampledomain.com";

 $ArrayOfStrings = explode(".", $url);

 echo $ArrayOfStrings[1];
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I annotated this code to make it readable. Do some research next time:

```
<?php

$url = "http://members.exampledomain.com/";
$url_parsed = parse_url($url);
$host = $url_parsed["host"];
$host_exploded = explode(".", $host);

echo $host_exploded[count($host_exploded) - 2];

?>
```

Comment: this worked 
`code`
<?php
 $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

 $ArrayOfStrings = explode(".", $url);

 echo $ArrayOfStrings[1];
 include("variables/" . $ArrayOfStrings[1] . "/config.inc");
 ?>
`code`

Comment: What happens if you have this url: `http://a.s.d.example.com/index.php?foo=.bar` ;)

Comment: all domains on my system will have the same subdomain http://members. the only thing that will change is the main domain